# Generalized Jacobi-Madden equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

I already posted this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746879/generalized-jacobi-madden-equation), but received no answers other the some useful cases.

The [Jacobi-Madden equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Madden_equation)
$ a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4 = (a+b+c+d)^4 $
has an infinitude of integer solutions with all variables non-zero.

Is it known if the same is true for the general equation $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^n = (\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i)^n$ ?

I tried to look for some references, but found nothing.

Comment: Certainly not when n=2.